# Can smart contracts deploy other smart contracts?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

If a smart contract has the compiled bytecode for a contract can the first deploy a subsequent contract?

According to Ethereum.org:
"To deploy a smart contract, you merely send an Ethereum transaction containing the compiled code of the smart contract without specifying any recipient."

I looked for how to send a transaction via smart contracts and the closest I could find were examples for transferring ETH...

```
    _to.transfer(msg.value);
  
    bool sent = _to.send(msg.value);
   
    (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
```

Answer (score 8):

to make a smart contract deploy another smart contract you can do it with the use of the new keyword

```
contract UserMessage {
  string message;
  constructor(string memory message){
     message = _message;
  }
}

contract DeployUserMessage {
  mapping(address => address) userToContract;
  
  function Deploy(string memory message) public {
    address contractAddress = new UserMessage(message);
    userToContract[msg.sender] = contractAddress;
  }
}
```

I think this example make it clear, but if you want, check the docs https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html#creating-contracts

Comment: As of Solidity V5, you should write:
`address contractAddress = address(new UserMessage(message));`

Answer (score 4):

Yes It can, and it's called ***Factory Pattern contracts***

```
contract Child {
    string public name;
    string public gender;

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _gender) {
        name = _name;
        gender = _gender;
    }
}

contract Parent {

    Child public childContract; 

    function createChild(string memory _name, string memory _gender) public returns(Child) {
       childContract = new Child(_name, _gender); // creating new contract inside another parent contract
       return childContract;
    }
}
```

> **New** Keyword is used to create contract in another contract function.

##### If it is a payable contract then :

```
contract Child {
    string public name;
    string public gender;

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _gender) payable {
        name = _name;
        gender = _gender;
    }
}

contract Parent{

    Child public childContract; 

    function createChild(string memory _name, string memory _gender) public payable returns(Child) {
require(msg.value == 0.005 ether)
       childContract = new Child{value: msg.value}(_name, _gender); // creating new contract inside another parent contract
       return childContract;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to call the parent's constructor if you are inheriting. For example, let's say you have "Name" contract

```
contract Name {
    string public name;

    constructor(string memory _name) {
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

Now my base contract should inherit from "Name" contract

```
// I deployed a new Name contract
contract Base is Name("Ronaldo"){}
```

Answer (score 0):

To deploy smart contract in smart contract.
you have to import smart contract code and call construct by using new keyword.

```
import "A.sol";

A a = new A(argumnet) // construct arguments

address(a) // deployed smart contract address
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can always deploy a smart contract from another smart contracts. You may familiar with the term **Smart Contract Factory**, **Factory** contracts are used to deploy new smart contracts. Following code is a simple Factory contract to create *ERC20 Tokens* that you can refer. But if you want to master this I will add some links at the end of the answer.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// Import the ERC-20 interface
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

// Factory contract to create ERC-20 token contracts
contract TokenFactory {
    // Event emitted when a new token is created
    event TokenCreated(address indexed creator, address indexed tokenAddress);

    // Function to create a new ERC-20 token
    function createToken(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint256 _initialSupply) external {
        // Deploy a new ERC-20 token contract
        ERC20Token newToken = new ERC20Token(_name, _symbol, _initialSupply, msg.sender);

        // Emit an event with the creator's address and the new token's address
        emit TokenCreated(msg.sender, address(newToken));
    }
}

// ERC-20 token contract
contract ERC20Token is ERC20 {
    // Address of the creator
    address public creator;

    // Constructor to initialize the token
    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint256 _initialSupply,
        address _creator
    ) ERC20(_name, _symbol) {
        // Mint initial supply to the creator
        _mint(_creator, _initialSupply);

        // Set the creator's address
        creator = _creator;
    }
}
```

Refer the article at https://www.quicknode.com/guides/ethereum-development/smart-contracts/how-to-create-a-smart-contract-factory-in-solidity-using-hardhat to get a broader knowledge on Contract Factories.